# Thermal conductivity unit

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to type the unit for thermal conductivity w/mK in my document using the `siunitx` package but I get the wrong output.

I'm writing `\SI[per-mode = symbol]{113}{\watt\per\metre\kelvin}` which should give me the output "113 W/mK" but it gives me "113 W K/m"

I have no idea why it does this fliparound but it annoys me to death!

Comment: `\SI[per-mode = symbol]{113}{\watt\per{\metre\kelvin}}` -- You have to group the denominator units

Comment: @ChristianHupfer is right. It's like when you're doing calculations on the calculator or in a program, it you want to calculate `12/(3*4)`, you have to write `12/3/4` or `12/(3*4)`, `12/3*4` equals `48/3`

Comment: Please unaccept my answer and accept Joseph's answer. I want to delete my answer, which I can't do as long it's accepted

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `\per` modifier applies to *one* unit unless you set `sticky-per`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI[per-mode = symbol]{113}{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin}

\SI[per-mode = symbol, sticky-per]{113}{\watt\per\metre\kelvin}

\end{document}
```

Note that in this formulation brackets are needed to ensure that the nature of the division is correctly shown.

---

To understand why the standard settings expect a `\per` for each unit, it's important to bear in mind that with 'symbolic' input, `siunitx` parses the entire unit then constructs the output accordingly. Thus unlike the earlier [`SIunits`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunits) package, `\per` doesn't just drop in a `/`.

Taking the example `J mol^{-1} K{-1}`, this is read in English as

> joules per mole per kelvin

which is what inspires the notation `\joule\per\mole\per\kelvin`, where each inter-unit gap represents a multiplication of units. When written with a solidus, we need brackets in the demonstrator (`J/(mol K)`) as the alternative is mathematically incorrect (`J/mol K = J K/mol`).

As users want a variety of input forms, the package offers `stick-per` to allow for the 'one per to separate out the numerator and denominator' approach, hence allowing `\si[sticky-per]{\joule\per\mole\kelvin}` to work. However, this is still parsed into the same internal format as `\si[sticky-per = false]{\joule\per\mole\per\kelvin}`, and so will still add any brackets required to maintain mathematical meaning. That behaviour too can be altered using the `bracket-unit-denominator` setting, so in a document where you want '`SIunits`-like' behaviour the appropriate set up might be

```
\sisetup{bracket-unit-denominator, per-mode = symbol, sticky-per}
```

(I would apply this on a whole-document basis.)

Note that when you use `per-mode = symbol` and have a reciprocal unit part-way through the input, `siunitx` reorders such that the `/` is correctly positioned based on the parsed units. That is perhaps clearer if you force fractional form

```
\SI[per-mode = fraction]{113}{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin} =
  $113\,\frac{\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{K}}{\mathrm{m}}$
```

Finally, `siunitx` allows the use of literal input (not everyone needs or likes parsed units)

```
\SI{113}{W/m.K}
```

Comment: I found a PDF made by Marcel Heldoorn where on p 24 he writes "Mixed case The mixed case should be simple now; the unit of thermal conductivity
(watt per metre kelvin):
1. Use your just-learned-knowledge:\watt\per\metre\usk\kelvin
2. The result is: ‘W/m K’.
Now, you can do it all in one step! Intuitive & simple."
I thought I could simply skip the '\usk' and use it like that

Comment: Even now, I'd contest the result. The 'm K' part should definitely go into parentheses.

Comment: @MartinHL That's from the docs for `SIunits`, not `siunitx`. I'll edit to explain the differences here.

Comment: After finding the right PDF for the siunitx package I foud the function {per-mode=fraction} and used it to get the unit displayed just the way I like it.
\SI[per-mode=fraction]{113}{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin}
This also makes a small space between the m and the K to awoid it looking like milliKelvin.
Thanks for the great package that I know know how to use :-)
@JosephWright

Answer (score 8):

The units in the 'denominator' (meter and Kelvin) must be grouped before they are accepted as one bundled 'unit', otherwise the 'division' goes wrong. The best is to use `\per\metre\per\kelvin` to make it clearer that (mK) is meant and not milli-Kelvin

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI[per-mode = symbol]{113}{\watt\per\metre\kelvin} is not the same as \SI[per-mode = symbol]{113}{\watt\per{\metre\kelvin}}

\SI[per-mode =symbol]{113}{\watt\per\metre\per\kelvin} is the best variant since it does not look like Milli-Kelvin
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MartinHL: Yes, but see Joseph's answer. He's is the author of `siunitx` ;-)

Comment: Doesn't this look like Watt per milli-Kelvin?

Comment: @jknappen I went with `[per-mode=reciprocal]` for everything in my thesis as I had a lot of Wm⁻¹K⁻¹ and wasn't happy with any of the W/mK, W/m K, W/m⋅K, W/m/K, W/(m K),... options.

Comment: @jknappen: Yes, somehow, but the `(m K)` isn't really nice either. If the O.P. is happy with it, all is right, otherwise he can accept Joseph's answer of course